# How to create an object based on filtering two arrays with a filter criteria from one array in Javascript/ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's assume I have two arrays of the same length:

```
const arr_one = [1,2,null,4,null,6];
const arr_two = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
```

Now I would like to create one object called `arr_final` out of it that uses the values of `arr_two` as `keys` and the values of `arr_one` as `values` for `arr_final`, but only for values in `arr_one` that are not `null`.

So the desired outcome would be:

```
const obj_final = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "d": 4, "f": 6}
```

**Current solution**

Currently, I am having a for loop with an if check inside it and would like to change it to a more shorter code:

```
let arr_final = {};
for (const [i, v] of arr_one.entries()) {
    if (v != null) {
        arr_final[arr_two[i]] = v
    }
};
```

**How can I achieve this with a minimal number of code lines?**

Comment: Your current code is quite reasonable. I wouldn't change it (except for the `let` -> `const`, and the `==` to `===`). Another option is `Object.fromEntries` and `.filter`, which would be more functional, but probably longer

Answer (score 1):

Here's the shortest one-liner approach, that requires 1 array iteration only

```js
const arr_one = [1,2,null,4,null,6];
const arr_two = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];

const fa = arr_one.reduce((a, e, i) => e ? { ...a, [arr_two[i]]: e } : a ,{});
console.log(fa);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks optimal, here is an another version to your solution:

```js
const arr_one = [1,2,null,4,null,6];
const arr_two = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];

let arr_final={}
arr_one.map((itm,indx)=>{
  if(itm!==null){
    arr_final[arr_two[indx]]=itm
  }
})
    console.log(arr_final)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use lodash zipObject utility
Here is a reference: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#zipObject